# UISlider thumb image is hidden on sliding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have set thumb image for UISlider. This image is not reflected when i drag the slider. Once I finish the dragging then It is appearing.

I have set the image for all states

```
    [self.myslider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kPlayerScreenHandleImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.myslider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kPlayerScreenHandleImage] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Setting it just for `UIControlStateNormal` state should be sufficient enough. Could you please check if when dragging you are not passing any empty image for thumb image or setting thumb tint colour to clear colour. Can you please post your value changed handler method. as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `UIControlStateHighlighted` to Show thumb image while dragging.

like below.

```
[self.myslider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kPlayerScreenHandleImage] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: The best solution... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should set both images, that is while normal and also during highlight

```
 rangeSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named : "yourImage"), for: .normal)
 rangeSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named : "yourImage"), for: .highlighted)
```